# Nextjs with websockets for chat app deployed on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, websocket, next.js, socket.io, google-cloud-memorystore

i had created a small app using nextjs and had deployed it on google cloud run. I was thinking of adding in a chat feature and could not figure out the best way to approach it. All i know is i dont want to use another 3rd party software but just do it with websockets / socket.io.

nextjs says that i can just create the socket server under the /api folder but with cloud run im assuming that might cause issues when there are multiple instances running and ill have to worry about synchronizing the data with like a redis database https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets#multiple-instances. its just this gets super expensive.

I was thinking what if i just created a new websocket/socket.io server and deployed it on a cheap compute engine as if i understand correct that is just going to be one VM and always up right? and then the nextjs app can just keep running on cloud run and then connect to the compute engine websocket server when they navigate to the chat app. I was then even thinking to move all my database logic over to this application which is hosted on compute engine so the nextjs app can just ask the new server for all the data when it needs to populate the data.

Is there any other better solution or is there issues with this approach im not thinking of? i dont get much traffic so i dont need any crazy strong VM that will cost be a lot hence i was thinking of going this route and this might help me seperate the UI and the backend server. mainly liked nextjs for the SSR content as my FAQ pages and all are SEO friendly over all the additional over head i would have had to do with a react app.

Comment: Can you provide the instance properties of your memorystore instance? I've followed the documentation you provided and it is under basic tier with 1GB capacity, 1GB max memory, 500 MB/s maximum network throughput and the estimated cost is around $35.77 per month. Please check this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LseXw.png) for reference.

Comment: Hi Robert, actually I just noticed that for some reason I thought I had seen a much bigger price. So regarding the application tho, should I just place the socket in the api folder for nextjs application or now I’m confused if I should create another application and host that on cloud run. So total 2 cloud run apps, one nextjs while the other is a socket server and then the memory store. Or just have one cloud run

Comment: I guess I’m short the question turns out to be I know I can use socket.io with nextjs, but should I? I can’t seem to figure out the pros and cons. Just because it can be done I’m not sure if that’s the best to do

Comment: I haven't tried using Next.js. I've used Node.js using this guide in [building a WebSocket chat service for Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/websockets). I've successfully deployed a sample chat service using this guide. Another guide that I found is [building a chat app using Next.js and Firebase](https://www.cometchat.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-chat-app-with-nextjs). Hope this helps.

Comment: Did my previous comment address your concern?